# Codeigniter 4: Helper function which is loaded using BaseController is not available in library unless the helper is loaded in library too

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Previously I was using Codeigniter 3 and I load all helpers, libraries using the `autoload.php`. Now migrating to CI4 where I tried the following,

1. I tried loading my helper files in the `BaseController.php`
2. I tried loading the helper in `__construct` at my `Controller.php` as well.

I have a Library say Demo.php and function `check_user_logged()`. When I called my `get_cookie()` from the function, it says `Call to undefined function App\Libraries\get_cookie()`.

This function `check_user_logged()` when it is called from a controller as,

```
<?php
use App\Libraries\Demo;

protected $demo;

public function __construct()
{
    helper('cookie');
    $this->demo = new Demo();
}

public function index()
{
    $this->demo->check_user_logged();
}
```

The Demo.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Libraries;
Class Demo
{
   public function check_user_logged()
   {
      print_r(get_cookie('name')); // just for simplicity printing the cookie
   }
}
```

Is it the only way to load the cookie helper in Demo library constructor? Or I am missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer loading a helper in a specific function/class ***that needs it***.

##### Option 1:

Loading the *cookie* helper in the library's constructor.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Libraries;
class Demo
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        helper('cookie');
    }

    public function check_user_logged()
    {
        print_r(get_cookie('name')); // just for simplicity printing the cookie
    }
}
```

##### Option 2:

Loading the *cookie* helper in the library's method.

> The [helper function
> `get_cookie()`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/cookies.html#id10)
> gets the cookie from the current `Request` object, not from
> `Response`. This function checks the `$_COOKIE` array if that cookie
> is set and fetches it right away.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Libraries;
class Demo
{
    public function check_user_logged()
    {
        helper('cookie');

        print_r(get_cookie('name')); // just for simplicity printing the cookie
    }
}
```

##### Option 3A:

Getting the cookie in the [current Response's cookie collection](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/cookies.html#id10).

```php
<?php

namespace App\Libraries;
class Demo
{
    public function check_user_logged()
    {
        print_r(\Config\Services::response()->getCookie('name')); // just for simplicity printing the cookie
    }
}
```

##### Option 3B:

Using the [`cookies(...)`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html?highlight=redirect#cookies) global function. No need to load any helpers.

> Fetches the global `CookieStore` instance held by `Response`.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Libraries;
class Demo
{
    public function check_user_logged()
    {
        print_r(cookies()->get('name')); // just for simplicity printing the cookie
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer Steven. So I understand that there is not option like CodeIgniter 3 to load the helper in one file, say autoload.php and access it anywhere in the project, right. Because there will be some custom created helpers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Loading the generic CI4 **cookie** helper in the BaseController should work.

```
protected $helpers = ['cookie','my_security_helper' ];
```

Can you post your original faulty code?